# Preparing wheel metadata ... error ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1 while installing apex

Tags: python, installation, pip, apex, python-wheel

what i am doing

```
pip install apex
```

what error it is showing-

```
Collecting apex
  Using cached apex-0.9.10dev.tar.gz (36 kB)
Collecting cryptacular
  Using cached cryptacular-1.5.5.tar.gz (39 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\lenovo\anaconda3\new_folder\python.exe' 'c:\users\lenovo\anaconda3\new_folder\lib\site-packages\pip\_
vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpgjm4o5t7'
         cwd: C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ngmptthv\cryptacular
    Complete output (52 lines):
```

i am struggling the same error with ***dataclasses==0.8*** please somebody help me out.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to install apex :

```
git clone https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex
cd apex
pip3 setup.py install

# or

pip3 install -v --disable-pip-version-check --no-cache-dir --global-option="--cpp_ext" --global-option="--cuda_ext" ./
```